# html form does not link to php file

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I have created a html form and want to connect it to a database on xampp. I have created the database and tables but the when I click submit, the php file does not work. I am new to web development. If I just run `http://localhost/connect.php` then it works but when I click submit on the form, it redirects to `file:///F:/Xampp/htdocs/connect.php` opens and shows the error. This is the html code for my form.

```
<form method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="connect.php">

    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="input-box" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,}"placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="input-box" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,}"  placeholder="Last Name"  required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="email" id="dataemail" name="dataemail" class="input-box" style="width: 48%;" placeholder="Your Email ID"  required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" id="datapass" name="datapass" class="input-box" style="width: 48%;" placeholder="Password"  required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" class="input-box" style="width: 48%;" placeholder="Date of Birth" onfocus="(this.type='date')" min="1901-01-01" max="1999-12-31"  required>
    <br>
    <p style="font-size:150%;">

    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male" required>
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female">
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="Other">
    <label for="other">Other</label>
    </p>

    <p><span><input type="checkbox" required></span> I agree to these <a href= "##">terms and conditions </a></p>
    <button type:"button" class="signupbutton">Sign Up</button>

    <hr>
    <p class="or">OR</p></form>
```

This is my php code

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost' ;
    $username = 'root' ;
    $password = '' ;
    $db = 'task';

    $fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fname');
    $lname = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'lname');
    $dataemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fdataemail');
    $datapass = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'datapass');
    $dob = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'dob');
    $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'gender');


    $conn =new mysqli("$dbhost", "$username", "$password", "$db" );
    echo "Connected to db";

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `signup` (`First name`, `Last name`, `Email ID`, `Password`, `Date of Birth`, `Gender`)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$dataemail','$datapass','$dob','$gender')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

[image: The error]

Comment: You cannot access a PHP file as `file://`..

Comment: My submit button redirects it to this address even though both my html and php files are in the same folder i.e. F:\Xampp\htdocs

Comment: tried `action="http://localhost/connect.php"`?

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: `onSubmit="return validateForm();"` Can you post what `validateForm()` does?

Comment: Vote to close this question

Comment: Are you opening your form via localhost, like `http://localhost/form.html`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the connection between `<html>` and `<php>`.  `<php>`  seems to be not properly connected to the database.

`<button type:"button" class="signupbutton">Sign Up</button>`: No "=" after "type".

Comment: No. When I just run php file I get **Connected to dbNew record created successfully**. and database shows new data.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **PHP** version and if possible update the question with that information too. If you are working with **PHP** version prior to `5.2.9` and `5.3.0` you have to use the following code as the `$connect_error` was broken until `PHP 5.2.9` and `5.3.0`

```
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

instead of

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Refer the official page of [mysqli construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it worked. Thanks.

```
action="http://localhost/connect.php"
```

Comment: The main reason is because you are accessing the `.html` via `file://` which is wrong. You should access the `.html` file via the full URL `http://localhost/myhtml.html`

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that. Thanks.